# Need a count of status codes that occurred over last 24 hours

Tags: sql

I need some help with a simple query, which pulls the recent job status codes from NetBackup's error log database.

I'm new to SQL (2nd day using it), but managed to put together a simple script to display the pertinent data and how to filter it by specific status codes.

My Question -- How can I modify this, to display a list of status codes found ... and number of times each occurs?

such as;

```
STATUS  COUNT
0       112
1        11
8         5
58        3
191       1
288       7
800       3
```

(I realize the example query has more data requested than is needed, but wanted to show the field names and such.)

```
SELECT
  id as 'Job ID',
  clientName as 'Client',
  mediaServerName as 'Media Server',
  statusCode as 'Exit Status',
  UtcBigIntToNomTime(startTime) as 'Start Time',
  UtcBigIntToNomTime(endTime) as 'End Time'  

FROM domain_JobArchive

WHERE
  DATEDIFF(hour, UtcBigIntToNomTime(endTime), GETDATE()) <= 24
  and
 statusCode = 1;
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow.  Please read the [FAQ] soon (not that you did anything wrong).  By showing what you had got working, it made it a lot easier to help you with an answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
SELECT statusCode AS STATUS, COUNT(*) AS COUNT
  FROM domain_JobArchive
 WHERE DATEDIFF(hour, UtcBigIntToNomTime(endTime), GETDATE()) <= 24
 GROUP BY statusCode
```

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT statusCode, COUNT(*)
FROM domain_JobArchive
GROUP BY statusCode
```